# Edit myself or just tag 'Requires Editing'?

Tags: discussion, edits, suggested-edits, triage

I've been reviewing posts in Triage now that I have the rep for it, and occasionally I will come across ones that require editing and that I am confident editing myself (code formatting, poor grammar/punctuation, etc). Is there a preference for whether I should perform these edits myself or just flag and move on?

On one hand, my edit will create work since someone has to review it; on the other hand, they just have to look at it instead of writing it themselves. But the fact that 'edit' is not accessible from the review page (I have to click through to the original first) makes me wonder if editing is being explicitly discouraged in Triage.

Comment: Very good question. I see triage as a pre-filter for the H&I queue. The editing is supposed to happen in the other queue, but i cant' think of why the option to do so would have been omitted entirely from the triage queue, other than for not *encouraging* users to edit, not necessarily to *discourage* it.

Comment: You're not supposed to be editing in the Triage queue, you're simply classifying posts in that queue. Also note that you should be making sure that the question is on-topic before marking it as Requires Editing. If you cannot edit the post to be on-topic, there is no reason to edit it.

Comment: @TinyGiant, I am just talking about cosmetic edits like a lack of code formatting or run-on sentences, on questions that I would otherwise vote "Looks OK". For questions that appear to have other issues I do try to flag appropriately (or just skip if I'm not sure). Thanks for the clarifications!

Answer (score 28, accepted):

The point of Triage is to spend no more than the bare minimum of time necessary to *classify* posts into broad categories of salvageability. So the queue does not encourage voting (except at carefully-metered intervals in one category), answering, interacting with existing answers, protecting, or editing. Those are thought to distract from the main purpose.

If you do want to do the job yourself, you can, but if you have less than 2k, it's probably best to <kbd>Skip</kbd> the review after opening in a new tab for editing, since you don't know for sure that your edit will go through and therefore can't be sure <kbd>Looks OK</kbd> is really correct.

Make sure you only select <kbd>Requires Editing</kbd> when there are *significant* edits that need to be made by whatever 2k user next sees it, since it will require someone to edit the post to get it out of Help and Improvement, and minor adjustments aren't worth burdening that queue. A bit of inferior formatting or a few minor misspellings are certainly not worth clicking that button. Examples of good reasons to select that (drawn from the [faq-proposed](/questions/tagged/faq-proposed) [Triage guide I drafted](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/295674/4099598)):

> - Overhaul its substantial spelling/grammar/formatting errors
> - Rewrite the title to represent the core of the problem
> - Remove useless and mistaken tags and add crucial, relevant tags
> - Pull code in from hosting site linked in question — if license is compatible
> - Incorporate important information from comments
> - Incorporate important information from mistaken self-answers (assuming you can see these, which is not usually the case)

Comment: Thanks for the answer, especially the point about significant edits. I'll keep this in mind going forward!

Comment: Note that "Requires editing" means significant edits need to be made, and **the edit can be made by anyone**.  If the edit can only be made by the OP (add missing information, for example), then the question is unsalvageable, and should be closed.

Comment: @Teepeemm: Yup!